# Camera exception in device but , same code works in emulator

Tags: android, android-camera

Code snippet:

```
   Camera camera=Camera.open();
```

My logcat output:

```
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demi/demi.bussiness.MakePhotoActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to get camera info
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to get camera info
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(Native Method)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:287)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at demi.bussiness.MakePhotoActivity.onCreate(MakePhotoActivity.java:71)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5244)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
01-17 16:28:01.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     ... 11 more
```

Everything works well in emulator but fails in my lg nexus device. Is it a hardware issue or something else?

Comment: you have to use `camera.release()` accordingly to make it work

Comment: but how does it work on emulator?

Comment: Your code snippet is too short to determine what's wrong. Please update your question.